# Pasar un listado de objetos de JavaScript a PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
function actualizarEstado(){
hi = Object.values(actualizaciones);
window.location = ('actualizar.php?actualizaciones='+ hi);


}
<?php
$actualizaciones= $_REQUEST['actualizaciones'];
print_r($actualizaciones);
?>
```

Actualizaciones es una variable contiene un listado de objectos donde establesco 2 id(iduser y idselect) entonces para insertar en base de datos utilzo php.

Pero me imprime lo siguiente: 
[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: No imprime nada al parecer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si `actualizaciones` es un objeto del tipo

```
{
 id_user: 1,
 id_select:2
}
```

Al concatenarlo con `actualizar.php?actualizaciones=` lo estás casteando a un String. Ese casteo siempre te dará `[object Object]`

Lo que podrías hacer para empezar (aunque no es la manera correcta en realidad) es convertir tu objeto en un string usando `JSON.stringify` y, del lado del servidor, volver a convertirlo en objeto (o array) usando `json_decode`.

```
function actualizarEstado(){
  hi = Object.values(actualizaciones);
  window.location = ('actualizar.php?actualizaciones='+ JSON.stringify(hi));
}

<?php
  $actualizaciones= $_REQUEST['actualizaciones'];
  print_r(json_decode($actualizaciones,true));
?>
```

Pero insisto, esta no es la manera correcta de hacerlo. Dependiendo de los valores en tu arreglo, tendrías que sanitizar lo que le pasas a la url adonde rediriges. Hay mil cosas que pueden salir mal con este enfoque al problema... pero si sólo estás experimentando supongo que bastará con esta respuesta para empujarte en la dirección correcta.

Sólo a modo de sugerencia: Se te haría todo más fácil si pasas el contenido de `actualizaciones` mediante Ajax.

Comment: Gracias me ha funcionado

Comment: @DiegoLopez considera aceptar la respuesta marcando el check de la izq. Un saludo

Comment: Saludos... Si claro Gracias.